# Как реализовать структуру комнатного чата?

Tags: android, база-данных, архитектура, сеть, chat

К хочу сделать свой чат, и как лучше сохранять сообщения и разделять их по комнатам?
К примеру есть текст сообщения я сохраняю его в бд с индификатором беседы датой и прочими параметрами, а когда пользователь заходит в приложение и выбирает нужную комнату то на сервер отправляется запрос с индификатором комнаты и приходит ответ с десятью или больше последними сообщениями.
Это мое видение решение проблемы, вот мне интересно есть какие нибудь другие решения данной проблемы ? как к примеру устроенно в pubnub итд ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не поверите, в данный момент занят как раз таким чатом. На сервере есть база данных с зарегистрированными пользователями. А для сообщений - другая база данных. Каждый чат соответствует таблице. В каждой таблице - сообщения. При старте приложение отправляет запрос на сервер и мне приходит `JSON` массив с комнатами. При клике на комнату отправляется запрос на получение последних 30 сообщений. При прокрутке вверх до конца происходит автоподгрузка сообщений. Вроде, ваша идея - идеал. Имхо, так бы поступил любой разработчик

Answer (score 1):

Делаем две таблицы:

1. Комната
2. Сообщение

Сообщение имеет отношение с комнатой многие-к-одному. То есть у одной комнаты может быть много сообщений.

- В первой таблице создаёте запись для каждой комнаты чата.
- Во второй таблице создаются сообщения со связью к одной из комнат.

Вот и все дела. Не для высоко-нагруженных систем такого решения более чем достаточно, можно хранить десятки тысяч, или даже сотни тысяч сообщений без проблем. Хотя чаще всего хранить столько сообщений нет никакой необходимости.